# Bind a detail report to a class model with properties stored in a Dictionary (VB.NET, Devexpress)

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm trying the example from Devexpress

```
Dim binding As New XRBinding("Text", dsProducts1, "Products.UnitPrice")
```

But my models does not have their properties explicitly written in their class. It would take a method GetProperty("column_name_here") to get it's data. I'm wondering if the 3rd parameter of XRBinding can be a method? Like:

```
Dim binding As New XRBinding("Text", dsProducts1, product.GetProperty("name"))
```

**Additional Info:**

All of my model classes extends this `Dao` class which is responsible in getting data in the database. The `Dao` class have a protected variable as a Dictionary(Of String, Object) to store the values (key = column name, value = column row value) from the database.

Now when I want to get something in the database, I only call

```
Dim user As New User // this class extends the Dao class

Dim userId = user.GetProperty("id") // Method to get the value from Dictionary, first parameter is the Dictionary key or column name from the DB
```

I made this so that I wont have to create every model class and set the properties of that class, as it is kinda cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are no way to bind to some method. I suggest you to take a look at [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) dynamic class. The members of this class can be added at runtime. This class implements `IDictionary(Of String, Object)` interface which you can use to generate properties from your `Dictionary(Of String, Object)`.

Here is example:

Example of base `Dao` class implementation with protected `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` property:

```
Public Class Dao
    Private _values As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    Public Sub New()
        _values = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    End Sub

    Public Overridable Sub Fill(index As Integer)
        _values.Clear()

        _values.Add("ID", index)
        _values.Add("Product", "Banana " & index)
        _values.Add("Price", 123.45 + index)
    End Sub

    Protected ReadOnly Property Values As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        Get
            Return _values
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Example of `Dao` class descendant with `DynamicValues` property which returns `ExpandoObject` based on `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` (you must omit the type of property):

```
Public Class DynamicDao
    Inherits Dao

    Private _dynamicValues As ExpandoObject

    Public Overrides Sub Fill(index As Integer)
        MyBase.Fill(index)

        _dynamicValues = New ExpandoObject()

        Dim keyValues = DirectCast(_dynamicValues, IDictionary(Of String, Object))

        For Each pair In Values
            keyValues.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)(pair.Key, pair.Value))
        Next
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property DynamicValues ' <= There is no type. In hint is displayed «As Object».
        Get
            Return _dynamicValues
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Usage of `DynamicDao` class in `XtraReport`:

```
Dim list = New List(Of DynamicDao)

For index% = 0 To 9
    Dim dao = New DynamicDao()
    dao.Fill(index%)

    list.Add(dao)
Next

Dim labelID = New XRLabel()
labelID.DataBindings.Add(New XRBinding("Text", Nothing, "DynamicValues.ID"))

Dim labelProduct = New XRLabel()
labelProduct.DataBindings.Add(New XRBinding("Text", Nothing, "DynamicValues.Product"))
labelProduct.LeftF = 50

Dim labelPrice = New XRLabel()
labelPrice.DataBindings.Add(New XRBinding("Text", Nothing, "DynamicValues.Price"))
labelPrice.LeftF = 150

Dim detail = New DetailBand()
detail.Controls.Add(labelID)
detail.Controls.Add(labelProduct)
detail.Controls.Add(labelPrice)

Dim report = New XtraReport()
report.Bands.Add(detail)
report.DataSource = list

report.ShowRibbonPreview()
```

Comment: Wow, I never knew that class exists. I'm gonna play with this. I'm currently away from my workplace. Just for the sake of confirming it. So normally, when I'm gonna get a property of a Dynamic Dao, I'll just call `dynamicDao.DynamicValues.Price` right? Neat!

Comment: @MarkVizcarra Yes, just call to `dynamicDao.DynamicValues.Price` property and you get the price.

Comment: @MarkVizcarra I've corrected my answer. You must omit the type of `DynamicValues` property to make it works.